# Magento 2: Login user programmatically showing wrong default header message "Default welcome msg!" instead of showing "Welcome, user!"

Tags: magento2, programmatically, magento2.2.6

When you login to Magento 2.2.6 programmatically with code below, header show default message "Default welcome msg!" instead of "Welcome, user!"

```
// Load customer session
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

**Expected result**

- Session should get started
- Header should show "Welcome, user!"

**Actual result**

- Session getting started
- Header shows "Default welcome msg!"

Unlike when you login with magento login page, it is not picking customer fullname during login with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The welcome message on header using customer data scope.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml

You'd need to trigger invalidate for customerData after your action

```
customerData.invalidate(['customer']);
customerData.reload(['customer'], true);
```

For example

- Event trigger

  ```
  $(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {
      var sections,
          redirects;

      if (settings.type.match(/post|put/i)) {
          sections = sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(settings.url);

          if (sections) {
              customerData.invalidate(sections);
              redirects = ['redirect', 'backUrl'];

              if (_.isObject(xhr.responseJSON) && !_.isEmpty(_.pick(xhr.responseJSON, redirects))) {
                  return;
              }
              customerData.reload(sections, true);
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- Use section sections.xml file to etc/frontend for controller/action

  ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
  <action name="braintree/paypal/placeOrder">
      <section name="cart"/>
      <section name="checkout-data"/>
  </action>
  </config>
  ```